# How to join 4 formula together

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I was wondering is there able to combine and compare multiple condition in excel.

Here will be my initiate data:

```
      N          O        P          Q        R         S        T         U    
 1:  USL        UCL     Target      LCL       LSL
 2:  3.5         3       2.5          2       1.5
 3:
 4:  DATE     PROCESS   DATA       OOS-USL  OOC-UCL   Normal   OOC-UCL  OOS-LSL
 5: 5/15/14    32451    4.000      TRUE      FALSE    FALSE    FALSE     FALSE
 6: 5/15/14    32454    3.400      FALSE     TRUE     FALSE    FALSE     FALSE
 7: 5/15/14    32454    1.800      FALSE     FALSE    FALSE    TRUE      FALSE
 8: 5/15/14    32448    1.400      FALSE     FALSE    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE
 9: 5/15/14    32447    2.800      FALSE     FALSE    TRUE     FALSE     FALSE
```

I was wondering is there possible to populate the data like below:

```
      N          O        P           Q        R
 1:  USL        UCL     Target       LCL      LSL
 2:  3.5         3       2.5          2       1.5
 3:
 4:  DATE     PROCESS   DATA       REMARKS
 5: 5/15/14    32451    4.000      OOS-USL
 6: 5/15/14    32454    3.400      OOC-UCL
 7: 5/15/14    32454    1.800      OOC-LCL
 8: 5/15/14    32448    1.400      OOS-LSL
 9: 5/15/14    32447    2.800      Normal
```

It will compare the data with all USL,UCL,Target,LCL,LSL and return the result with words.
For example,

- if the data is bigger than USL(3.5), it will return result "OOS-USL"
- if the data is bigger than UCL(3) but smaller than USL(3.5), it will return result "OOC-UCL"
- if the data is smaller than LCL(2) but bigger than LSL(1.5), it will return result "OOC-LCL"
- if the data is smaller than LSL(1.5) , it will return result "OOS-LSL"

Curretenly I have my formula as below:

```
Formula in Q:5: =IF(P12="","",IF(P12<>"",P12>$N$2))
Formula in R5:=IF(P12="", "",AND(IF(P12>$O$2,P12<$N$2)))
Formula in S5:  =IF(P12="","",AND(IF(P12>$Q$2,P12<$O$2)))
Formula in T5:=IF(P12="", "",AND(IF(P12>$R$2,P12<$Q$2)))
Formula in U5:=IF(P12="", "",IF(P12<$R$2,"TRUE","FALSE"))
```

Is there possible to combine all formula together and return the result as I mention earlier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Remarks =IF(P5>$N$2,"OOS-USL",IF(AND(P5>$O$2,P5<$N$2),"OOC-UCL",IF(AND(P5>$R$2,P5<$Q$2),"OOC-LCL",IF(P5<$R$2,"OOS-LSL","Normal"))))
```

This is basically a series of nested ifs to check which range the data belongs to. If you wanted to retrieve the text dynamically, you could change the hard-coded values to use the cell reference as well, like so:

```
IF(P5<$R$2,"OOS-"&$R$1,"Normal")
```

Comment: Hi, thank you~ this work perfectly. I have learn new thing again~

Answer (score 0):

try this version :

=IF(A5>$A$2,"OOS-USL",IF(A5>$B$2,"OOC-UCL",IF(A5>$D$2,"Normal", IF(A5>$E$2,"OOC-LCL",IF(A5>$E$2,,"OOS-LSL")))))